# Ionic button ng-click is sometimes not recognized

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app that wraps a certain web-app that uses angular.

There, I have some buttons like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="Orders">
  <ion-content scroll="true" overflow-scroll="true">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- some other divs with text only -->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button type="button" ng-click="vm.go('orders.new')" 
           class="button btn btn-lg btn-info">new order</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Sometimes the method `vm.go()` is not called when I tap/touch on the button. In Chrome (Browser) and Android, it is always working right. Even if I open the page via the normal safari browser on iOS, everything is working.

So, it seems to be a problem with ionic and/or cordova.

If I attach an event handler manually (with plain JavaScript using `getElementById()`) to the button to detect touch or mouse events, they are fired, but `ng-click` is not. If this happens and the button's method is not correctly fired, the view scrolls/sets instead the view to the top.

For me, it looks like some kind of a race-condition, so that there is sometimes the correct behaviour (ng-click is invoked) and sometimes it is not.

Using Ionic 1.3.2 and cordova 6.0.0

Does someone has any idea for that?

Comment: Can you provide the parent element of your button, please?

Comment: Yes - updated my question!

Answer (score 0):

There is one div that blocks click from 330ms,

On "beforeenter" add:

```
angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('click-block')).addClass('click-block-hide');
```

With this the wiev will be responsive from begining.

Comment: Why is this div there in the first place?